# -bash: export: `Workbooks.app/Contents/SharedSupport/path-bin': not a valid identifier

Tags: bash, export

I know it's been many topics related to this, but I couldn't solve my problem.
Anytime I open the Terminal on MacOS I get this message

> -bash: export: `Workbooks.app/Contents/SharedSupport/path-bin': not a valid identifier

What should I do?

Comment: Do you have any scripts running automatically when you open the terminal? Check `/etc/profile`. Also check for `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, and `~/.profile`

Comment: You have a bad `export` command in one of your bash startup scripts, like `.profile` or `.bashrc`.

Comment: Type `grep 'Workbooks.app/Contents' .*` to find the script that has it.

Comment: I found a script related to that >.bash_profile:export PATH=~/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/share/dotnet:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands:/Applications/Xamarin Workbooks.app/Contents/SharedSupport/path-bin

Comment: how do I delete it?

Comment: Edit the `.bash_profile` file, don't delete it.  Then logoff and login again.  However, I suspect this is not the line, but that you have another, side the error message indicate that the path name is used as a variable name.

Comment: I did that and it worked. Thanks!